# MySQL subquery on itself returns all records

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

The following query returns all results, but according to my understanding should return the same ID's as the subquery. Could somebody explain why the subquery that returns all ID's (when ran separately) returns all records

```
select mya.id from mytable mya WHERE mya.id IN (
   SELECT myb.id 
   FROM mytable myb
   GROUP BY myb.mysecondcolumn
)
```

The subquery when ran as individual query would for example return 1,5,10,15, but when I run this query above it returns 1,2,3,4,5,...

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, adding the sample data that produces the unexpected result would help, thx.

Comment: @JNDPNT Are subquery and main table are same?

Comment: Any time you find yourself using a GROUP BY clause absent any aggregating functions, you can be pretty much certain that you're doing something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is malformed.  You need an aggregation function in the subquery.  Perhaps:

```
select mya.id
from mytable mya 
where mya.id in (SELECT MIN(myb.id)
                 FROM mytable myb
                 GROUP BY myb.mysecondcolumn
                );
```

This does not explain your actual problem.  My guess is that the subquery *is* returning all ids, but just in a different order.  You can check if this is the case by looking at the results of:

```
SELECT MIN(myb.id)
FROM mytable myb
GROUP BY myb.mysecondcolumn
ORDER BY MIN(myb.id)
```